# How to disable/enable h:datatable

Tags: jsf, datatable

I have a page with a h:selectOneMenu and a data table. I want to load/render/enable my h:datatable based on what I select in the h:selectOneMenu. Is this possible?

Here's some code

```
<tr class="portlet-table-body" >
<td width="20%" class="porlet-padding-left"><h:outputText value="${operatorProgramBundle.NextGenerationWorkflow}" /></td>
<td width="450px">
    <h:selectOneMenu id="ngw" styleClass="portlet-dropdown"  value="${CRUDOperatorProgram.selectedNextGenWorkflow}">
        <f:selectItems value="${CRUDOperatorProgram.nextGenWorkflowList}" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
</td>
```

```
<h:dataTable id="DispatchConfigurationCustom" columnClasses="portlet-table-same portlet-table-cell"
headerClass="portlet-table-same portlet-table-cell" value="#{CRUDOperatorProgram.workflowConfigList}" var="workflowConfig" width="100%" >
<h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Include" />
    </f:facet>
    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="includeInd" value="#{workflowConfig.isIncludedInd}"/>
</h:column>
<h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Automate" />
    </f:facet>
    <h:selectOneRadio id="onOff" value="#{workflowConfig.isAutomatedInd}">
        <f:selectItem id="onButton" itemLabel="On" itemValue="0" />
        <f:selectItem id="offButton" itemLabel="Off" itemValue="0" />
    </h:selectOneRadio>
</h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible in JSF 2 using the `<f:ajax update="DispatchConfigurationCustom">` tag inside the `<h:selectOneMenu>`. If you're using JSF 1.2, you would need a third party library that handles ajax interaction like RichFaces 3.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Is it possible to have the datatable not disabled and then when something specific from the h:selectOneMenu is selected, the datatable enables? Do you mind showing me an example?

Comment: "Enable/disable" is a strange term in the context of a HTML `<table>` element (which is generated by `<h:dataTable>` component). Don't you rather mean "show/hide"? Further, are you using JSF 1.x or 2.x? The way you put the code (this is syntactically valid for JSF 1.x on JSP) and the word "portlet" smells much like a legacy JSF 1.x portlet.

Comment: Okay. And are you using JSF 1.x or 2.x? That's really important to know before an answer can ever be posted by anyone. Many things are done differently and more elegantly in JSF 2.x thanks to the new builtin ajaxical capabilities.

Answer (score 2):

Given that you're using JSF 2.x, just use `<f:ajax>` in the dropdown to update the closest parent of the datatable and let the `rendered` attribute of the datatable evaluate `true` or `false` accordingly depending on the selected item.

Assuming that you'd like to show the datatable only when item value "foo" is selected, do so:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.selectedItem}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.availableItems}" />
    <f:ajax render="table" />
</h:selectOneMenu>

<h:panelGroup id="table">
    <h:dataTable rendered="#{bean.selectedItem == 'foo'}">
        ...
    </h:dataTable>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: So when I looked at documentation, I saw that h:datatable did not have a "rendered" property associated with it. I'm guessing f:ajax render="table" allows that property to be used?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. It's definitely [listed](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/dataTable.html) as tag attribute in the documentation.

Comment: Oh wow, I must of been looking at wrong documentation! So this code will render the datatable when a specific selection is made. Also, what if I unselect that "specific" selection. I'm assuming it won't un-render will it? Essentially what I'm trying to do is make a page with default input areas with a drop down that has selections in it along with a "Custom" selection. When you select "Custom" from the drop down, the datatable appears. If "Custom" is selected and then you unselect it, I would like the data table to disappear and so on, like a disable/enable. Is the second part even possible?

Comment: Seems like I'm actually using a4j and a4j:ajax will not work. Any ideas?

Comment: It should work fine with `<a4j:ajax>` as well. Your problem is caused elsewhere. Hard to tell based on the information provided so far.

Comment: It says: "Tag Library supports namespace: http://richfaces.org/a4j, but no tag was defined for name: ajax]" None of the online examples specify a tag for ajax though. Confusing.